# Using Firebase, how can I create a query based on UID?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a function that adds a UID to the database along with an item's state:

```
changestate(item) {

    var postData = {
      state: "listed",
    };

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid;

    var updates = {};
    updates['foods' + '/' + item.$key + '/' + 'state' + '/' + uid] = postData;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  }
```

I want to create a query that only shows the data corresponding to that UID. In a previous query I was using:

```
getLists(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
return this.db.list('/foods', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'state',
    equalTo: 'listed'
  }
});}
```

This is the structure of my database:

```
{
  "foods" : {
    "foodID1" : {
      "category" : "Produce",
      "foodname" : "Apples",
      "state" : {
        "aePQkvozV6gehP7ihjN0OWCltKu2" : {
          "state" : "listed"
        }
      }
    },
    "foodID2" : {
      "category" : "Dairy",
      "foodname" : "Cheese",
      "state" : {
        "aePQkvozV6gehP7ihjN0OWCltKu2" : {
          "state" : "listed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to show the items that correspond to a signed in user's UID?

Answer (score 0):

The `orderByChild` property can take a path. So the code then simple becomes:

```
getLists(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
  return this.db.list('/foods', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'state/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/state',
      equalTo: 'listed'
    }
  });
}
```

This requires that the user is signed in of course. To test the query without a signed-in user, you can use a hard-coded value:

```
getLists(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
  return this.db.list('/foods', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'state/aePQkvozV6gehP7ihjN0OWCltKu2/state',
      equalTo: 'listed'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Using this gave me the following error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_firebase_app__["auth"]().currentUser.uid')

Comment: Could this have to do with the query being referenced here: `ngOnInit() {

        this.moviesSvc.getLists().subscribe(lists => {console.log(lists); this.lists = lists})
      }`

Comment: That sounds like your user isn't signed in yet, in which case the query is not possible. I added a snippet with a hard-coded UID, just so you can test the query.

Comment: I was able to confirm that the user is signed in with: `getLists(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {console.log("blah", user.uid)
        // User is signed in.
        var uid = user.uid;
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });

    return this.db.list('/foods', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'state/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/state',
        equalTo: 'listed'
      }
    });
  }` however, I'm still getting the same error.